# Chrome lighthouse report returns `Properly defines charset` issue in Best Practices section

Tags: html, vue.js, utf-8, character-encoding, lighthouse

I have a VueJs SPA application. Everything is working fine. But when I run chrome lighthouse report, it returns `Properly defines charset` error. In fact I have added charset in my index.html file.

**Here are screenshot of issue.**

***Chrome light house report***

[image: Chrome light house report]

***Chrome lighthouse issue in best practices***

[image: Chrome lighthouse issue in best practices]

***Code where I added charset UTF-8***

[image: Code where I added charset UTF-8]

Comment: You should love more the `"` character. Try with `charset="utf-8"`, ans possibly add `"` in all other places (good coding style, but so it is also more compatible with all browsers)

Comment: thanks a lot for replaying @GiacomoCatenazzi. I have added `"`, but webpack remove this string when creating build. I have another application like this one, and its has no this kind of issue.

Comment: Note: to me, it seems a bug of Google, but maybe there is a special character (that it is not so visible).  But so a note: you should copy your text as text, not as picture (so we could test it)

Comment: Here is my HTML structure of my index.html file
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    ......
  </body>
</html>`

Answer (score 0):

It was service worker issue. I was unintentionally double registering service worker. that`s why its creating problem.

Comment: may I ask you how you discovered this? It has happened to me, too, but in my case I was not registering the service worker twice, but making a test where the service worker called `skipWaiting()` on `install` event and `clients.claim()` on `activate`event. I'm very curious, because I'm doing a correct usage of that scheme and I don't know why the charset test fails! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and it also points to worker
and my worker installs:

```
self.addEventListener("install", event => {
    event.waitUntil(installEvent());
    self.skipWaiting();
});

async function installEvent() {
    const response = await fetch(createCacheBustedRequest(OFFLINE_URL));
    const cache = await caches.open(CURRENT_CACHES.offline);
    await cache.put(OFFLINE_URL, response);
}
// od poprawnego przeładowania zakłądek
self.addEventListener('message', async event => {
    if (event.data === 'reloadClients') {
        const clients = await self.clients.matchAll({type: 'window'});
        for (const client of clients) {
            client.navigate(client.url);
        }
    }
});

self.addEventListener("activate", event => {
    event.waitUntil(handleActivation());
    self.clients.claim();
});

async function handleActivation() {
    let cacheNames = await caches.keys();
    let validCacheNames = Object.values(CURRENT_CACHES);
    let deletePromises = [];

    for(let cacheName of cacheNames) {
        if(!validCacheNames.includes(cacheName)) {
            //console.log("Deleting out of date cache:", cacheName);
            deletePromises.push(caches.delete(cacheName));
        }
    }

    await Promise.all(deletePromises);
    
    // Po wykonaniu wszystkich operacji czyszczenia, przeładuj wszystkie zakładki przeglądarki.
    self.clients.matchAll({type: 'window'}).then(windowClients => {
      windowClients.forEach(windowClient => {
        windowClient.navigate(windowClient.url);
      });
    });
}
```